# Excel how to auto populate text value with color if condition is met

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have an excel sheet where three columns exist for three browser types.

If test cases pass for all three browsers, the Result column should be marked as Pass with Green color. The values for the three browser columns can be either:
Pass, Fail, In Progress, TBD, Out of Scope

How can we achieve this through a worksheet formula?
Detailed example given below:

```
Web Browser1      Web Browser2       Web Browser3        Result
Pass              Pass               Pass                Pass(Green)- Only If all status is 'Pass'
Pass              Pass               Fail                Fail(Red)- If any 1 fails then result will be fail
TBD               In progress        Pass                In Progress(Yellow)- If any 1 is 'In Progress', result is 'In Progress'
```

Trying out something like:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H2:J2,"Pass")=3,"PASS",IF(COUNTIF(H2:J2, "Fail")>=1, "FAIL", 
IF(COUNTIF(H2:J2, "In Progress")>=1, "IN PROGRESS", IF(COUNTIF(H2:J2, 
"TBD")>=1, "TBD", IF(COUNTIF(H2:J2, "Out Of Scope")=3, "OUT OF SCOPE", "")))))
```

Comment: You can build formula like `=COUNTIF(A2:C2,"Pass")=3` to calculate the outcome and then associate colors with the outcome.

Comment: What results do you expect when say one cell holds `Fail` and one cell has `In Progress`? Have you tried to build any formula so far?

Comment: If any 1 cell contains 'In Progress' the final result should be also 'In Progress'. I have formula to populate by checking 1 column: =IF(H3="Pass","Pass",IF(H3="Fail", "Fail", IF(H3="Out of Scope","Out of Scope", IF(H3="TBD", "TBD", "In Progress"))))'

Comment: Demonstrate results then for `TBD` and `Out Of Scope` as well by editing the main post. Currently you have omitted them. Or are they not required?

Comment: TBD and Out Of scope is similar to the Pass condition. If i can generate for the three examples given in main post, i can extrapolate for other conditions

Comment: You asked for a formula, but you also added the tag for VBA, is this an option, because this can easily be achieved through code?

Comment: OK. Here's an approach for you to test. Assuming your data is in cells `H3:J3` you can try formula like `=IF(COUNTIF(H3:J3,"Pass")=3,"Pass",IF(COUNTIF(H3:J3,"In Progress")>0,"In Progress",IF(COUNTIF(H3:J3,"Fail")>0,"Fail",IF(COUNTIF(H3:J3,"TBD")>0,"TBD","Out of scope"))))`.

Comment: once you have the result column giving PASS, Fail etc then you can build a series of conditional formats to apply the colours.